# append div after executing $post

Tags: jquery

Greeting, I would like to append some div after correct success is returned from my $.post 
My code looks as follows:

```
$.post("/MyApp/Market/CheckIfIndustryIsValid", { id: $(NODE).attr("id") },
            function(obj) {
                if (obj.Success) {
                    if ($.inArray($(NODE).attr("id"), array) === -1) {
                        array.push($(NODE).attr("id"));
                        $("#Industries").val(array);
                        arrayOfNames.push($(NODE).attr("title"));
                        $("#SelectedIndustries").html($(NODE).attr("title"));
                    }
                    else {
                        array.splice(array.indexOf($(NODE).attr("id")), 1);
                        $("#Industries").val(array);
                        arrayOfNames.splice(array.indexOf($(NODE).attr("title")), 1);
                        $("#SelectedIndustries").val(arrayOfNames);
                        $("#resultMessage").append($(NODE).attr("title")); 
                    }
                }
                else {
                    alert("Please choose different industry"); //failure, show message
                }
```

However these lines:

```
$("#SelectedIndustries").val(arrayOfNames);
$("#resultMessage").append($(NODE).attr("title"));
```

are not working. For test purposes I also added some alert("test") just before these two lines and it has been executed. Can someone please help.

Comment: Well what type of element is `#SelectedIndustries` ? You are trying to assign an array as value...

Comment: it's div. Well look at this line $("#resultMessage").append($(NODE).attr("title")); It also does not work

Comment: It probably is not executed because the previous line throws an error.

Comment: no..it does not throw an exception

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you been able to get any results by using `alert( $(NODE).attr("title") )`? (Or using [the Firebug Console](http://getfirebug.com/logging), if you are using Firefox.)

Have you checked the value of `arrayOfNames`? I can see the `.slice()` and `.push()` actions, but what is the original, and subsequent, values of that variable?

Also, setting the `.val()` attribute of a `div` is not possible. If you are trying to set the contents of the `div`, then you will need to use `$( '#selectedIndustries' ).innerText( 'The Contents of the DIV' )`, or `...).innerHTML( 'The <b>Contents</b> of the <i>DIV</i>' )` (if the contents contains HTML tags).